# Using variables with jQuery's replaceWith() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok this one seems pretty simple (and it probably is). I am trying to use jQuery's replace with method but I don't feel like putting all of the html that will be replacing the html on the page into the method itself (its like 60 lines of HTML). So I want to put the html that will be the replacement in a variable named qOneSmall like so

```
var qOneSmall = qOneSmall.html('..........all the html');
```

but when I try this I get this error back

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I don't see any reserved words in there..? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried `var qOneSmall = '..........all the html'` ? , without calling `.html()` ?

Comment: When I try this I still get the same error

Comment: _"When I try this I still get the same error "_ Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Here is a link as requested https://jsfiddle.net/djarrin/o1bfor9t/

Comment: The string at `pOneSmall` at https://jsfiddle.net/djarrin/o1bfor9t/ does not appear properly escaped ? Try removing space , newline characters between elements within string between single quotation marks `''` . Additionally , jQuery not appear loaded at jsfiddle ? Appear to be `pOneSmall` at variable declaration , `qOneSmall` within `checkViewPort` ?

Comment: Go ahead and post that as an answer it worked! I'll up vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only looking to replace text then jaj.laney's `.text()` approach can be used.  However, that will not render the string as HTML.

The reason the way you're using `.html()` is likely illegal is that `qSmallOne` is not a JQuery object.  The method cannot be performed on arbitrary variables.  You can set the HTML string to a variable and pass that string to the `.html()` function like this:

```
var htmlstring = '<em>emphasis</em> and <strong>strong</strong>';  
$('#target').html(htmlstring);
```

To see the difference between using `.html()` and `.text()` you can check out this short [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/by3jm23w/1/).

### **Edit after seeing the HTML**

So there is a lot going on here.  I'm just going to group these things into a list of issues

1. The HTML Strings

So I actually learned something here.  Using the carriage return and tab keys in the HTML string is breaking the string.  The illegal-ness is coming from the fact the string is never properly terminated since it thinks it ends at the first line.  Strip out the white space in your strings and they're perfectly valid.

2. Variable Names

Minor thing, you've got a typo in `qSmallOne`. Be sure to check your spelling especially when working with these giant variables. A little diligence up front will save a bunch of headache later.

3. Selecting the Right Target

Your targets for the change in content are IDs that are in the strings in your variables and not in the actual DOM.  While it looks like you're handling this, I found it rather confusing.  I would use one containing element with a static ID and target that instead (that way you don't have to remember why you're handling multiple IDs for one container in the future).

4. Using replaceWith() and html()

`.replaceWith()` is used to replace an element with something else.  This includes the element that is being targeted, so you need to be very aware of what you're wanting to replace.  `.html()` may be a better way to go since it replaces the content within the target, not including the target itself.

I've made these updates and forked your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dsajucpy/1/).

Comment: I guess fuyushimoya was sorta of correct, the issue I am running into is actually setting the variable not so much the method I suspect. Here is a sample of the code I am trying to use to set the variable: `var htmlstring = '<div class="mobile-show" id="qOne_small">.....many more lines';` but I still get the original error stated

Comment: I've expanded my answer to include some of the things I noticed in your fiddle.  Point 3 is more maintenance preference, but points 1 and 4 should help you better understand the problems you're facing

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is to only grab the element on the page you're interested in. You say you have like 60 lines. If you know exactly what you want to replace..place just that text in a div with an id='mySpecialText'. Then use jQuery to find and replace just that.

```js
var replacementText = "....all the HTML";
$("#mySpecialText").text(replacementText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySpecialText">Foo</div>
```

Comment: Please read the complete document, as [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) DID have another usage that accepts parameter.

Comment: `.html()` does accept an argument depending on what you're using it for.  Using it to get HTML takes no arguments, but using it to set HTML can take an argument to set a target element's HTML value

Comment: My appologies, you are right. I suppose either .html(string) or .text(string) could be used in this case. I think I missunderstood the question in the first place. You create a variable for either methods by using simple text `var replacementText = "bar";`

Comment: We don't need apologize, I just want you to fix the first paragraph, as any answer that provide wrong information can't be consider a good answer even its what the OP want, as it may mislead other reading it.

Comment: Well one of the problems is that I can't have both of the blocks of html on the page at once (otherwise I would just use media queries). So I need to have one or the other on the page depending on the view port width (it's a form and one layout is completely different than the other depending on what the view port width is, if I have both on the form, when the form is submitted what ever the values in the field farthest down the page is the one that gets submitted).

Comment: perhaps using jquery's attach/detach methods may be more usefull. This way you can keep your HTML separate from your JS. https://api.jquery.com/detach/